# HTTP sites are not working while HTTPS sites are in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, google-chrome, proxy

I can't reach http websites in any kind of browsers in my desktop (ubuntu 16.04) while https websites load without any problem.

I have disabled network proxy and set all browsers proxy setting to none but still no luck.

I removed chrome and firefox cache and data and checked again but the result is the same.

**Updated**
When I try : `curl -v http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu`

I get this out put in result :

```
*   Trying 140.211.9.4...
* Connected to wiki.ros.org (140.211.9.4) port 80 (#0)
> GET /lunar/Installation/Ubuntu HTTP/1.1
> Host: wiki.ros.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 15 Feb 2018 08:36:46 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Vary: Cookie,User-Agent,Accept-Language
< Content-Length: 39312
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
```

When it happen and won't load anything I get this response when using curl :

```
 curl -v http://shop.roboticngo.com/
*   Trying 138.201.86.61...
* Connected to shop.roboticngo.com (138.201.86.61) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: shop.roboticngo.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: do they work with `wget`? What is the error in the browser and if it doesn't work : in `wget`?

Comment: Did you do a '`sudo apt-get update`' and update your system with all the latest repo's normally you will see a 'NoEntry' Symbol on top-right corner on your screen which disables updates. Unless manually intervened. what I'm trying to get you at is to keep everything upto date and install latest version of chrome/firefox if installed.
Could you specify in more detail like when did this stop working. Did it work before? did you do a fresh install of Ubuntu?

Comment: @RobertRiedl No it doesn't work in wget either I get no data received in response.

Comment: @ShazeAn Every thing is up to date and I did sudo apt-get upgrade to make sure but still no change, it's a month i'm using this version of ubuntu and this problem started to happen from a week ago but I can't figure it out what's the cause

Comment: is it possibly something network related ? Do you have any other devices in the same network (Laptop, Smartphone, etc) ? Things you can try : Installing certificates with `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`, try `curl -v https://askubuntu.com` and paste **the whole output** as edit of your question.

Comment: @RobertRiedl I have ca-certificates and when I do curl -v on https:://askubuntu.com it works and loads the page, the problem is http websites which I can't get any response from them.

Comment: Sorry ! Then try the same with a http site (hard to find these days) `curl -v http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu` - this should give us some insight.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Thanks for responding, Yeah it worked : check the updated post

Comment: this is strange curl works, but wget doesn't ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl This is strange but now both wget and curl are working and also in the browser! I'm getting crazy why this is happening.

Comment: so, its not reproduce able any more ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl For now yeah, but i know it will happen again, while there is no clue whats the cause

Comment: @RobertRiedl That problem happened again and when I try to load http website it wont work :

Comment: Sounds like a (transparent) HTTP proxy that intercepts HTTP connections but not HTTPS (for whatever reason) and maybe not for all HTTP clients (since Curl appears to work). What kind of internet connection do you have? Any chance that the provider runs such a proxy on your connection?

Comment: It sounds to me like specific addresses you are trying to reach are using [interactive blocking](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/firepower/60/configuration/guide/fpmc-config-guide-v60/fpmc-config-guide-v60_chapter_01011100.pdf) to deny http requests.

Comment: @DavidFoerster No there isn't any kind of proxy on my connection from isp because my colleague have no problem with it. it's just me after installing ubuntu 16.04 and after a month using it facing this issue

Comment: @ElderGeek I don't think so, as I said my friends and colleagues have no problem opening that specific website it's just me.

Comment: @Mohammad_Hosseini The expected thing to do with new relevant information is to [edit] it into your post. We have no way of knowing in advance information that you don't include in your post and as this is a Q & A site and not a forum comments are often deleted for a number of reasons.

Comment: I had same problem in my ubuntu 18.04. HTTP url browsing dosn't work for websites that located on my server. Actually everything messed up after ssh login to this server. So I could browse those urls only via HTTPS. Some says I have change my MTU, but it didn't work and it was more interesting after changing my internet connection at the same machinie everything works find. But the problem occurred again after ssh login.

Comment: According to my colleage's advice (Mohammad Rashedi), I've edited network setup and changed from DHCP to manual and put 8.8.8.8 into DNS and the problem solved. Hope helps someone